# Sistema de voto com loop While e Rand()

Tags: php, html, loop, while

Estou fazendo um site com um sistema de voto, mas as imagens mudam de lugar com a funçao `Rand()`.

Até ai tudo bem, mas, na hora de votar, quando eu clico em um botão, o único que funciona é o botão da primeira imagem, com o `ID = 0`.

Aqui está o código:

```
 <?php

        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=studio_photo_cergy_compte','root','rootroot');

        $i=0;

        $rep = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM participant ORDER BY rand()');

        $name_value="concurrent";

        if(isset($_POST[$name_value.$i])) {

            $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);

            $reqmail = $bdd->prepare("UPDATE participant SET vote=vote+1 WHERE id =".$i);
            $reqmail->execute(array($vote));

            header("Location: merci_vote_sans_connexion.php");
        }

        while($photo = $rep->fetch()){
    ?>

        <img src="images/<?php echo $photo['image'] ?>">

        <form action="" method="post" align="center">
            <?php echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"".$name_value.$i."\" value=\"Voter\">"; ?>
        </form>
        <br><br>

        <?php 
            $i++;}
            $rep->closeCursor();
        ?>
```

Eu entendo por que o `$i` é sempre igual a `0`, já que o `if(isset)` está fora do `while`, e a incrementação do `$i` está dentro do *loop*, porém, já testei de vários jeitos e não consigo fazer com que cada botão corresponda a uma imagem diferente no meu banco de dados usando esse `while`.

Como resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é justamente pela linha `if(isset($_POST[$name_value.$i]))`

Como você mesmo percebeu, a variavel `$i` será sempre zero e o trecho de código desse if só executará quando o primeiro botão (o zero) for clicado.

Uma forma de você fazer isso é adicionar a variável `$i` no **value dos botões**.
Veja abaixo um exemplo de como poderia ser o form:

```php
  while($photo = $rep->fetch()){
    ?>

        <img src="images/<?php echo $photo['image'] ?>">

        <form action="" method="post" align="center">
          <button name="votar" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo 'Votar '.$i; ?></button>
        </form>
        <br><br>

        <?php 
            $i++;}
            $rep->closeCursor();
        ?>
```

Então a verificação com `isset()` ficará parecido com:

```php
    if(isset($_POST['votar'])) {
        $id = $_POST['votar']; // armazena o value do button que no loop é definido com o id (variável $i)
     // segue o restante do se código

        $reqmail = $bdd->prepare("UPDATE participant SET vote=vote+1 WHERE id =".$i);
        $reqmail->execute(array($vote));
        header("Location: merci_vote_sans_connexion.php");
    }
```

Agora a variável `$id` possui o value do botão que foi clicado e daí você poderá recuperar cliques em qualquer botão.

**NOTA:** Me referi a variável `$i` como id pois é com ela que você está fazendo a consulta em `$reqmail = $bdd->prepare("UPDATE participant SET vote=vote+1 WHERE id =".$i);`

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou sim, eu nao sabia como pegar o valor do $i dentro do While, mas eu entendi, obrigado :)

Comment: Que bom @MathisMaudet. Se puder marcar a resposta como válida, poderá ajudar quem tem dúvidas semelhantes.

Comment: Pronto, é que eu sou novo no site, nao sabia que tinha que fazer isso, mas esta feito agora ^^